# Distribution of the cosine of an angle of a random oriented vector in a sphere

Tags: geometry, probability-distributions, angle, spheres

I can't wrap my head around a problem, I have a methane molecule, which is basically a tetrahedron, and I orient one of its bonds (let's say from atom 1 and atom 2) along the $z$ axis of a  cubic box.

Now I know that the probability distribution for the angle $A$ between the 1-2 vector and the $z$ axis would be shaped as a sine function, but i think I understood that $\cos(A)$ instead should have a flat probability $P[\cos(A)]$ distribution (from [https://www.lockhaven.edu/~dsimanek/puzzles/hatbox.htm#:~:text=While%20puzzling%20how%20to%20find,radius%20R%20and%20height%202R.%22](https://www.lockhaven.edu/%7Edsimanek/puzzles/hatbox.htm#:%7E:text=While%20puzzling%20how%20to%20find,radius%20R%20and%20height%202R.%22)) .

Now If I make my molecule rotate around the  $y$ axis, so that I have 360 structures all equispaced of 1 degree I expected to see a flat $P[\cos(A)]$ distribution, and instead i get a distribution shaped like this:

[image: distribution of Pcos(A)]

Then I tried to get random numbers between 0 and 360 and use them to rotate the molecule around $x, y$ and $z$ of that number of degrees, and I still get the same distribution.

Then I tried to get three random numbers between $-1$ and $1$ and using arccos of those numbers to rotate the molecule around $x,y$ and $z$. And I still get the same shape of the distribution.

Can someone help me wrap my head around this?

Comment: What do you mean with the bond 1-2: C-H or H-H?

Comment: I mean one of the C-H, but it shouldn't be relevant since it's still just a vector randomly oriented in 3d

Comment: So it is just vector rotated from the axis by some angle with all angles being equiprobable, is it? And what does your graph show?

Comment: My graph is the histogram of the cosine of A taken from that ensemble of structures, so it would be the probability of each value of cos(A), which I though it should be flat, but it's not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is the distribution of the random variable $Y=\cos (X)$, where the angle $X$ is a random variable with the probability distribution function $$f_X(x)=\frac1\pi\quad\text {for}\quad 0 \le x \le \pi. $$
[Note that we need not to consider the range $[\pi,2\pi]$ in view of $\cos(2\pi-x)=\cos x$.]

Let us solve the problem using the distribution function technique. First we find the cumulative probability distribution function:
$$F_Y (y)=P (Y\le y)=P (\cos (X)\le y)=P (X\ge \arccos (y))\\
=\int\limits_{\arccos(y)}^\pi f_X (x)dx=1-\frac1\pi\arccos (y) .$$
The probability density function is then:
$$f_Y (y)=\frac d {dy}F_Y(y)=\frac1 {\pi\sqrt {1-y^2}},
$$
in (at least qualitative) agreement with the result of your numerical simulation.

Comment: But wouldn't the theorem that I linked mean that the probability of a vector to fall in a certain ring of the sphere corresponding to a small cosine intervall dcos(A) is constant for any value of A? When should I expect a flat distribution? I think there is some conceptual trap that I am stuck in and I cannot figure out where it is. May be that equally distributed points on a sphere are not distributed with an angle of 1/pi ? Also could you please link to a reference on how you derivated that probability density function?

Comment: In the theorem the *sphere* is sliced into discs of equal width. In your calculation the *circle* is sliced into sectors of equal angle. There is no reason to rely on one case while considering the other. My answer is self-containing. No further reference is needed. If you wish you may search in internet for distribution function method.